# Kaleidoscope and mandala generation tools?

Tags: images, image-processing

Are there any good tools (free or paid) to easily create kaleidoscopes/mandalas and save them as vectors? Preferably that allow to use the outcome for commercial purposes / sell it.
Tool types: online generators, soft for Windows or Ubuntu, easy to run scripts, Processing programs.
Outcome examples:
 [image]

Answer (score 2):

Have you performed a search with your preferred internet search engine? A quick hit on The Google for "mandela svg generator" gave up a large number of results. The first one, [mandela creator](http://mandalacreator.com/),  has links to github, which implies open source. There is no reference to licensing nor to restrictions.

An SVG save button also exists on the site, as well as a large number of user created designs.

There are some talented artists whose work is posted there.

[image: mandela image]

I did not pursue the results from all of the search links returned, only this one, as it appeared to be the most promising. As I lack artistic skills, my attempt to create will not be published.

If you are an Inkscape or Illustrator user, there are also tutorials on the 'net to assist you in creating your own. This search is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: Thank you for proposing  mandela creator, I will check it out. It's currently unavailable for me, probably the reason I missed it. It's the only one that looks decent in search results though. And I would really appreciate answers without the "use search engine!11" part.

Comment: the search engine reference is because that's how I found the linked programs. If you cannot access a linked reference, your country may have restrictions that prevent you from getting good results from your preferred search engine. Equally valid is that you did not state that you searched for the desired programs, suggesting no access or some other aspect overlooked.